# Automatically Upload CSV to Webapp Upload Form

Tags: python, forms, post, file-upload, web-applications

How can I make a bot which will automatically go to a file upload form on my webapp at a public link, click the upload a file button, select a file and submit it?

For example, I have a file called "stored.csv" on my desktop, and I have a webapp with an upload for that looks like this:

[image]

All I'm trying to do is have a script which can grab that stored.csv file, go to the public link (http://website.com/upload/) that takes you to this page and then submit the file so that it all happens automatically when the script is run.

Comment: I'm going to guess you haven't tried anything yet? This is a very broad question.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I've explored a lot of things, tried using requests since the file that I'm trying to read is created using a raspberry pi (uses sensors, collects data and stores it in a csv) but it became a mess, the web app is not hosted on the same device as the file I want to be automatically uploaded, so I can't send it via requests.FILES in my webapp code so now I'm looking for a solution which takes the webapp entirely out of the picture aside from the public link and a file on a seperate device. It seems like a simple thing to do but I can't find a good example of how to accomplish it

Comment: @AlexanderCécile just keeping it simple because putting everything else aside, this is all I'm trying to do and then all the rest of my project will come together but the rest isn't relevant to the task here :)

Comment: Just to be sure I understand things correctly, you tried using `requests` to POST the file, and it didn't work out?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I had tried requests within the pi script that was creating the stored.csv file, but not as was suggested here

Comment: Where is the file from, and where is it going?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the file comes from the raspberry pi, which has no connection to the device that hosted the web app, and the file is going to http://website.com/upload/ where the upload form for the website is at

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203204/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-daniel-decker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to send post request that button does right away.
All you need to do is to:

- On that page open **dev. tools** in your browser (F12 most likely)
- In appeared window click on the **"Network"** tab
- Then leaving this window opened, choose any file and click "submit"
- New record will appear at the end in "Network" tab containing information about the request that was made

---

Then knowing the request that you need to make, you can easily implement it in python:

```py
import requests as req

url = "Url that you will acquire"
data = {
    "smth" : "path/to/file"    # just copy the body from the known request
}

res = req.post(url=url, data=data)

print(res.status)
```

And that's it. 
There is some stuff that you'll need to figure out by your own, but now you got a map.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! It is very helpful :) I get status code 403 when I use this can you think of why that might be? Should my RequestUrl be the same as http://website.com/upload/ ?

Comment: @DanielDecker #403 code means "Permission denied". That means that the service that you need to upload file to requires authentication. For automatic authentication several methods can be used e.g. `requests.Session()`. I can't provide all the info in the comment, but your future research on this topic will lead you to answer, that's for sure. Good luck!